# Run the image for Docker no see results

Tags: docker

I used this command and got related response:

```
$ docker run -t -d -p 80:5004 myapp
a940b8bc522e593a83181ef95138f25dd1f3100bd6ff563d24eab7a265e9bd2a
```

But when I use `docker ps` to check the container see below response, it seems not correct (no see any info).

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED
STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

If I browse `http://localhost/api/values` on my host, I do not get the final result that I want.
Through the log I can see the error, but still not know how to fix it:System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'HelloMvc6' from /app/src/HelloMvc6

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your container did not start properly and stopped immediately due to an error. You would probably see an *exited* container process when you type `docker ps -a`.

You can have a look at the containers console output using `docker logs <containerId>` to see what went wrong.

**Hint**: Usually you do not need the `-t` flag (tty) when you run the container detached in background with the `-d` flag.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I see below exception message:System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'HelloMvc6' from /ap
p/src/HelloMvc6

Comment: Did you add those project files to the `/app` folder on the image during the `Dockerfile` build with an `ADD` or `COPY` statement?

Comment: This is my work folder's path:C:\Users\leiha\Desktop\testdocker\aspnet-Home\samples\latest\HelloWeb. Might it has some issue? cause I no app folder at all.